# How to call .net web service using CUrl PHP?

Tags: php, .net, api, curl

I have .net web service which i need to call using CUrl in php. Can anybody tell me how to achieve this? Below is my code which is not working and throwing Server Error.

Thanks in advance

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"sample url");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
            "APIKey=sample&sku=&UPC");


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);

$server_output = curl_exec($ch);

print_r($server_output);
curl_close ($ch);
```

Please see below error for more information:

[image]

Comment: Please Share Error. check with changing `true` in  `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);`

Comment: Can you set auth headers also.

    `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "username:password");`

Comment: it returns server error (5xx i suppose).. do you have access to this problematic server and see the logs? take a look on its error then work from there.

Comment: @EmptyBrain Please see screenshot added

Comment: @EmptyBrain tried changing CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER to true still gives same error

Comment: @ShankarKanase Error is in the server code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used nusoap libraries to call the .net webservices.

Check below link:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140189/PHP-NuSOAP-Tutorial